# Kodak ESP 1.2 Printer not printing on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, printing, kodak

We installed Ubuntu 12.04 for a friend's mother.  She bought a Kodak ESP 1.2 printer in the meantime which doesn't seem to work with it.  The printer is connected via usb.

She goes through the printer setup wizard.  She can go until test print but nothing comes out.

We have moved away from the area but can get remote access to the computer.

Is it possible to copy over a file from the install cd to somewhere on the computer itself?  Would mac drivers work if they used gutenprint etc?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

you could try selecting "KODAK HERO 9.1 AiO" these drivers work for my esp 1.2

Comment: So far has worked a treat for me, thanks for the info!  I have it installed over wireless (not USB) and used the HERO 9.1 AiO and it's been working fine.  Only tested documents so far but the print quality is great.